# Hooking Up Azure Web Site to On-Premise WCF Service

Tags: .net, wcf, azure

I'm hoping to build a hybrid application where I expose a specific WCF service hosted on-premise, behind-the-firewall with an Azure web site. The Azure web site will simply call my WCF service to get and put data.

I had thought there was a way with Azure Connect to an Azure Service to specific WCF services on-premise, but now that I've installed it on a sandbox machine on my network, I'm not sure that's the case. I'd prefer if I could lock down my connection between Azure and my network to only those WCF services that I've specified, for additional security.

what are my options for getting my WCF service exposed to my Azure web site?

Comment: At that level Azure web site is just a client calling the on site WCF Service and would need to open up the firewall to let the appropriated calls in and out.   Look at Azure Service Bus but it is message based.

Comment: Opening up the firewall's not really an option in the corporate setting. We can set up servers in the DMZ, but those servers are still vulnerable.

Comment: I'm looking at Azure Service Bus now... I'm assuming it's like BizTalk?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Azure Service Bus is your friend here.  What you're really looking to do is to enable a Service Bus Relay, specifically as overviewed here:

http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/net/how-to-guides/service-bus-relay/

Also, the service in your environment has to expose itself to Service Bus through your firewall.  You can find some handy tips here (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/ee706729.aspx) although often times the simple act of registering with Service Bus tends to give it enough information to NAT and traverse through your infrastructure.

Service Bus supports a wide variety of relay bindings, as documented here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/hh410102.aspx .

I have a presentation on my blog about Service Bus, and the sample code has two projects that specifically demonstrate the relay.  Take a look at http://www.stratospher.es/blog/post/slides-and-code-from-dallas-july-10-2012-windows-azure-cloud-summit and download the sample code there.  The two projects you want are "RelayDemoServer" and "RelayDemoClient".  The sample code configures the relay in code, but you can also do this via configuration if that's more your style.

In a nutshell, you essentially have to create the WCF endpoint for the service you want on the server side (in your infrastructure), and then create an equivalent relay binding in Service Bus.  Once that happens, you'll end up with a Service Bus hosted version of your internal endpoint.  It looks something like this:

```
// create the host itself...
System.ServiceModel.ServiceHost host =
    new ServiceHost(typeof(ProblemSolver));

// programmatically add the endpoints

// 1. the WCF endpoint "internally"
host.AddServiceEndpoint(
    typeof(IProblemSolver),
    new NetTcpBinding(),
    "net.tcp://localhost:9358/solver"
    );

// 2. the endpoint that is projected back through the service bus (note: NetTcpRelayBinding)
// This one will end up with a DNS name of "sb://[serviceNamespace].servicebus.windows.net/solver"
host.AddServiceEndpoint(
    typeof(IProblemSolver), 
    new NetTcpRelayBinding(),
    ServiceBusEnvironment.CreateServiceUri("sb", Microsoft.WindowsAzure.CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("ServiceBusNamespace"), "solver"))
        .Behaviors.Add(new TransportClientEndpointBehavior
            {
                TokenProvider = TokenProvider.CreateSharedSecretTokenProvider("owner", Microsoft.WindowsAzure.CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("ServiceBusSecret"))
            });

host.Open();
```

Then, on the client side, you simply consume the service via the Service Bus.  That looks like this:

```
var cf = new ChannelFactory<RelayDemoServer.IProblemSolverChannel>(
    new NetTcpRelayBinding(),
    new EndpointAddress(
        ServiceBusEnvironment.CreateServiceUri(
            "sb", 
            Microsoft.WindowsAzure.CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("ServiceBusNamespace"), 
            "solver"
            )
        )
    );

cf.Endpoint.Behaviors.Add(
    new TransportClientEndpointBehavior 
        { 
            TokenProvider = TokenProvider.CreateSharedSecretTokenProvider(
                "owner", 
                Microsoft.WindowsAzure.CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("ServiceBusSecret")
                ) 
        }
    );

using (var ch = cf.CreateChannel())
{
    Console.WriteLine(ch.AddNumbers(4, 5));
}
```

The secret sauce is the call to CreateServiceUri which figures out the SB hosted URI.

Hope this is helpful, but let me know if you need more,

Adam Hoffman

Windows Azure Blog - http://stratospher.es

Twitter - http://twitter.com/stratospher_es

Comment: Copy/pasted the server files over to a new project, and I'm getting an access denied error. Is there any config in the Azure Management Portal that I need to check?

Comment: Specifically, I'm getting a SecurityTokenException

Comment: By the way, thanks for the awesome reply... I was having a difficult time finding good info on Azure Service Bus Relay. I had thought it was going to be a chore, but it's really quite an elegant solution from MS.

Comment: I believe I may have an issue with Relying Parties, but I don't know how to confirm this

Comment: Nope, it's actually a proxy issue... nevermind all that I was saying above

Comment: You're welcome! Glad to hear that you got through the proxy issues, and yeah, I really think that Service Bus is one of the killer features in the Azure stack...

Comment: I don't have firsthand experience with ASB, but we've had a few teams here go with it and end up regretting it.  We've now gone with a VPN connection from our internal servers to Azure Web Sites and that has been much much smoother.

Answer (score 0):

At that level the Azure web site is just a client calling the on-site WCF Service and would need to open up the firewall to let the appropriated calls in and out.

Look at Azure Service Bus but it is message based.

- [Service Bus](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/ee732537.aspx)
- [Securing and Authenticating a Service Bus Connection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/dd582773.aspx)